# Forcing with a "shrinked" poset

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Assume, in $V$, that we have some forcing $P$, a $P$-name $\tau$ and some sentence in the forcing language $\varphi(\tau)$ (it may include other names but we focus on $\tau$). Now we take some countable elementary submodel $M$ such that $P,\tau$, the maximal element of $P$ and every other name mentioned in $\varphi$  are in $M$.

Assume that $P\Vdash \varphi(\tau)$. So in $M$, $P^M=M\cap P$ is also a poset with the same maximal element, $\tau^M$ is also a $P^M$ name, and by the definability of the forcing relation we can relativise $[P \Vdash \varphi(\tau)]^M$ so in $M$, $P^M\Vdash \varphi^M(\tau^M)$. (Was that right?)

Now we go back to $V$ and look at $P\cap M$. If I get it right, it is still a poset, and $\tau^M$ is still a name for it. Now I want to force with it over $V$, say with a generic $G\subset P \cap M$. Will I get that $V[G]\vDash \varphi((\tau^M)_G)$?

I believe the answer is "yes" from the elementarity and the fact that the forcing relation is definable, but there might be something I'm missing.

Also - if it matters we can assume (for the cases that interest me) that also $\tau \subset M$ - does it matter?

Comment: Why should $P^M$ be in $M$? It's a class forcing there, but it's not even definable as a class, since then it would have been equal to $P$ which is a set in $M$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I assume that I take a countable model such that $P\in M$ (it is not assumed to be transitive).

Comment: Yes, but $P\cap M$ is not an element of $M$ and it is not even a definable class of $M$. So you're not quite forcing in $M$ with this poset.

Comment: ok, I think I'm confused by this relativization part...

Comment: What is $\tau^M$?

Comment: @tci it is supposed to be "$\tau$ relativized to $M$" , or "as computed in $M$". But I think I mixed things up a bit over there...

Comment: What does that mean? Do you mean that $\tau$ is (or is equivalent to) a $P \cap M$-name? Also, $P \cap M$ is a countable partial order, so it is just Cohen forcing, so it is going to be a rather mild thing. On the other hand, I think that the concept of 'strong properness' might be what you are searching for.

Comment: @tci Yes I think I wanted $\tau^M$ to be a $P\cap M$ -name that somehow corresponds to $\tau$. Maybe it's just supposed to be $\tau \cap M$ as well. I admit that the question was not so well-put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no.

Starting with a ground model of $V=L$, let $\mathbb{P}$ be the Levy collapse of $\omega_1$ to $\omega$, and let $\varphi$ be the sentence "$\omega_1^L$ is countable." (Note that there is no $\tau$ here, since $\omega_1^L$ is definable. But if we like we can take $\tau$ to be the canonical name for $\omega_1^L$.) The point is that from $V$'s point of view, $\mathbb{P}\cap M$ is isomorphic to Cohen forcing, since $M$ is countable. So forcing with $\mathbb{P}\cap M$ over $V$ won't collapse $\omega_1^L$.

Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I think you do understand it (probably better than I do...). In this case, the canonical name for $\omega^L_1$ is not a subset of $M$, since it must be uncountable. Does that make any real difference? Say for example we talk about a c.c.c poset and a name for a real, which can be taken to be countable. Would there still be a counterexample?

Comment: Wait, sorry, I'm a bit confused. As I said, the canonical name for $\omega^L_1$ is not a subset of $M$. So the corresponding name $\tau \cap M$ would be different, and would actually be a name for a countable set I guess... So it is not exactly what I mean

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler OK, consider the sentence "$\omega_1^L$ is countable and $2$ is finite" - where $\tau$ is the canonical name for $2$.